# Get full-height on background images

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with responsive on my box with background image.I want my box to have the height of the background image, because my background-size is auto.

**html:**

```
<div class="index_boxs" id="discover_wines_index"></div>
```

**css:**

```
#discover_wines_index {
    background-image: url(/bulk/bg/wines_inactive.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Background images do not effect the size of the elements they are applied to. You have to set up styles for the container elements separately.

Comment: Does the image is dynamic? (different images, different size). If it's static then you can manually set the `height` and `width` for the `div` element according to the image. If it's dynamic then you need a JS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's an empty div, unless you set it a height, the height will always be zero. There's a few methods you can use to fix this, I've had success in the past with [Uncle Dave’s Ol’ Padded Box](http://daverupert.com/2012/04/uncle-daves-ol-padded-box/) trick.

It's similar to what you have above, however use **background-size: cover** and add a percentage padding based on the width of the parent element.

Example code from the website:

```
#meowmeow {
    background: url(http://placekitten.com/720/405/) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
  }
```

Comment: For webkit browser all is ok, but FireFox and Edge height zero is problem.

Answer (score 0):

First create IMG element that holds the picture... you can do it programmatically or statically (you can hide it if necessary):

```
<img id="imageid" src="/bulk/bg/wines_inactive.jpg" style="display:none;" />
```

Now find out the size of your image:

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

now resize you can resize your DIV element according to this. Example of resize using jQuery:

```
$('#discover_wines_index').width(width).height(height);
```